# Altering a table partition

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table with a partition. I have loaded the data into that table. Now,
Is it possible to drop the partition from that table, with out deleting the data that have been loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create a second table with the same schema and swap the empty table out for your current partition.

```
-- create tables
CREATE TABLE t1 (a string, b string) partitioned by (ds string);
CREATE TABLE t2 (a string, b string);

-- then swap partitions
ALTER TABLE t1 EXCHANGE PARTITION (ds = '1') WITH TABLE t2;
```

The other approach is to create a new, empty, partition:

```
ALTER TABLE sales
PARTITION (country = 'US', year = 2012, month = 12, day = 22)
SET LOCATION = 'sales/partitions/us/2012/12/22' ;
```

With either approach, your data will still be present. I wrote an [introduction to hive partitioning](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/03/introduction-to-hive-partitioning/) a while back that should be helpful.